# How to get rid of payum "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" error while working locally with wamp

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, curl, payum

With payumBundle under symfony2, when trying to complete a payment on my local server with wamp and windows I get an error:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I understood I could solve it by either:

- download a certificate and set curl.cainfo=cacert.pem in php.ini
  PROBLEM : when I do so, the error does not disappear
- set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER option to false
  PROBLEM : Where do I do this with wamp/windows ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary fix :

update the vendor class

```
vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/Bridge/Buzz/ClientFactory.php
```

and add the following code in the createCurl method:

```
    $client = new Curl();
    $client->setVerifyPeer(false);
```

Would be nice to find a way to update this from within the controller action... if someone has an idea, I'll take it!

**EDIT : see the following answer which does it without modifying vendors :**

[Overload symfony2 vendor class to set curl verify_peer option to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941061/overload-symfony2-vendor-class-to-set-curl-verify-peer-option-to-false/28960181#28960181)