# Overload symfony2 vendor class to set curl verify_peer option to false

Tags: php, symfony, curl, paypal, payum

Using the Payum bundle with `symfony2`, I have the common 
`unable to verify ssl certificate` error.

I couldn't get rid of it by changing `curl` options in `php.ini` or by setting `curl` options in my php code.

However, modifying the `vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Client/AbstractClient.php` class and setting the default `$verifyPeer` option to `false` finally allows me to use Payum and PayPal express checkout locally with wamp.

EDIT:
I can also override this class which uses the other one. I feel it's safer:

> vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/Bridge/Buzz/ClientFactory.php

How can I override this class (ideally conditionally ie in dev mode when I'm working locally) ?

Comment: I edited your post to format the code, thus making it easier to understand the problem you're trying to solve, and the methods you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the service `payum.buzz.client`. Just define it in your bundle which is registered after PayumBundle.

```
<service id="payum.buzz.client" class="Buzz\Client\ClientInterface"     factory-class="Payum\Core\Bridge\Buzz\ClientFactory" factory- method="createCurl">
        <call method="setVerifyPeer">
            <argument>false</argument>
        </call>
</service>
```

or in yml

```
services:
    payum.buzz.client:
        class: Buzz\Client\ClientInterface
        factory_class: Payum\Core\Bridge\Buzz\ClientFactory
        factory_method: createCurl
        calls:
            - [setVerifyPeer, [false]]
```